# What does the set $2\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What does the set $2\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

I know $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set that contains all the integer numbers, but what does $2\mathbb{Z}$ mean?

Comment: All multiples of 2

Answer (score 5):

$2\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of even numbers.

That is: $2\mathbb{Z}=\{2z\ |\ z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb{Z} &= \{ \cdots, -3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,\cdots\} \\
2\Bbb{Z} &= \{ \cdots, (-3\cdot2),(-2\cdot2),(-1\cdot2),(0\cdot2),(1\cdot2),(2\cdot2),(3\cdot2),\cdots\} \\
&= \{ \cdots,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,\cdots\}
\end{align}$$